# Clickable images in Python without using tkinter

Tags: python, button, clickable, clickable-image

I´m a newbie in programming, and I was looking for some code or tutorial on how to make a clickable image in python without the Tkinter library, but I didn´t found anyone. Anyway, I´m trying to make a music player in a game where you have to guess the name of song with hints like a short melody, but I need to click the "play.png" to play the melody and I don´t know how. Can anybody help me with this? Thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean by 'clickable image in python without the Tkinter library'

Comment: You're going to have to use _some_ GUI framework. Tkinter is just one of several that are available and is included with the distribution (you will need to download and install one of the others to use it).

Comment: Why are you against using tkinter? Are you wanting to do this without _any_ GUI toolkit?

Comment: I´m against Tkinter because it will create a new window, but I already have a window, and I want to add the play button to the screen I already have and don´t create a new one. I hope that you understand 

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned in the comments, there are several GUI frameworks or toolskits available other than Tkinter.

Here is a simple example using [viaduc](https://github.com/dtmilano/viaduc) and adapting its [helloworld.py](https://github.com/dtmilano/viaduc/blob/main/examples/helloworld.py).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from viaduc import Viaduc


class Presentation(Viaduc.Presentation):
    title = 'audio player'
    width = 496
    height = 336
    html = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    {{bootstrap_meta}}
    {{bootstrap_css}}
    <title>{{title}}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{frameless_close_button}}
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <p class="lead">Welcome to <em>Viaduc</em>, the simplest way of creating a GUI in python.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mx-auto" style="width: 90%;">
        <audio src="https://samplelib.com/lib/preview/mp3/sample-6s.mp3" controls="" controlslist="nodownload" style="width:100%"></audio>
    </div>
    {{bootstrap_js}}
  </body>  
 </html>
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Viaduc(presentation=Presentation(), args=['', '--frameless'])
```

which produces

[image]

and can play the audio sample.